(Isoparametric) Mapping of physical coordinates to their equivalent parametric coordinates on a reference element
I have some experiece with finite element methods (FEM), in general. However, I mainly worked with Cartesian grids -- i.e. using orthogonal (non-curved) elements.
Recently, I became interested in a generalized curvilinear formulation. Still, exclusive for quadrilateral-type elements only. In that context, my question is the following:
Say, I have obtained my grid from some mesh generator. This is in physical space (x,y) and the (physical) elements have curved boundaries, shown on the left (a) of the attached figure. Clearly, the coordinates (in red) are not necessarily "structured". The idea behind (DG-)FEM is to map the physical element onto a reference element in local coordinates (r,s) which generally is in: $[-1,1] \times [-1,1]$. The reference element can be seen in the middle (b) and right (c) panels of the figure.
The task here is to map the physical (x,y) coordinates (red) in (a), onto their equivalent parametric (r,s) coordinates (green) in (b). Once that is done, I can determine where the equidistant points are (blue) in (c) by interpolating via some shape functions, e.g. Lagrange polynomials, using the basis in green (b). Of course One may argue that using end-point-clustered points (e.g. LGL) are better off to avoid the Runge phenomenon, but that's beyond this fictitious simple example.
Hence, how do you solve for the green points, i.e. step 1. I reckon you need to do it iteratively, but I don't seem to find a nice way to accomplish this.
As a recap: The only given (in this simple example) here is some element in physical space that is curved (a). How do we obtain the equivalent nodes (green) in parametric space that correspond to these values?
I hope my question was clear? Hopefully, others find value in it too.


[EDIT]
I'll try to add some more details to clarify things, bear with me..
Recall, the mapping on these elements is done, such that a scalar quantity within the physical element is interpolated from its standard element, as follows:
$$
f( x(r,s), y(r,s) ) = \sum_i f_i \ell_i(r, s),
$$
where $\ell$ is the Lagrange function, given in 1D as:
$$
\ell_m(r) = \prod_{n \neq m} \frac{r - \xi_n}{\xi_m - \xi_n},
$$
where $\boldsymbol{\xi}$ are the basis/degrees-of-freedom on the reference element.
For example, if the mesh generator already provided us with an equidistant element in physical space, then $\boldsymbol{\xi}$ are also equidistant in reference space and you can establish the basis (Lagrange) functions and start the entire process.
However, if the starting physical elements are not "well-structured" or are slightly "ambiguous", similar to the red points in fig. (a), then how to you get those $\boldsymbol{\xi}$? You cannot use equidistant values in reference space, because the red points aren't equidistant..
By the way, in this case, $\boldsymbol{\xi}$ are the green nodes in (b). Also, in (c) you establish a "nicer" basis by converting those arbitrary values (green) into equidistant ones (blue) on the reference element. Of course, then you can determine their equivalent equidistant values in physical space and redefine the entire shape in (a), but that's trivial once the mapping is established.

The following procedure is based on a transfinite interpolation (TFI) and is not unique.

First of all, I assume that the points are given in a nodal representation. If this is the case, then the polynomial curves and the reference positions on the boundary are implicitly defined. If not, you have to consider, that each different representation changes the path of the boundary curves. Moreover, be aware that a nodal representation does not necessarily match the original geometry.

Anyway, if only the physical coordinates are provided you can find the reference positions on the boundary with an iterative method using the definition of the arc-length for each segment
$$
\mathcal{L}(x_1)=\int_{a}^{x_1} \sqrt{1 + \left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2 \,}dx.
$$
With the exact lengths you can assign each physical-point on the boundary to a reference-point on the boundary.

After having calculated the reference positions on the boundary you can derive the reference positions in the interior with an inverse tranfinite interpolation, which has also to be solved in an iterative fashion
$$
\begin{array}{lcrc}
\mathbf{x}(\xi, \eta)&=& (1-\eta) &\cdot &\mathbf{x}_1(\xi) \\
            &+& \eta &\cdot &\mathbf{x}_3(\xi)\\
            &+&(1-\xi) &\cdot &\mathbf{x}_2(\eta)\\
            &+&\xi &\cdot &\mathbf{x}_4(\eta) \\
            &-& \xi \cdot \eta &\cdot &\mathbf{x}_3(1)\\
            &-&\xi\cdot (1-\eta)&\cdot &\mathbf{x}_1(1) \\
            &-&\eta\cdot (1-\xi) &\cdot &\mathbf{x}_3(0) \\
            &-&(1-\xi)\cdot (1-\eta)&\cdot & \mathbf{x}_1(0)
\end{array}
$$


The transfinite interpolation is not a unique choice. There are different mappings connecting boundary and interior points, for example
Analytical mappings

Lagrange based TFI
Hermite based TFI (which also blends derivates)
NURBS based (aka Gordon surface)

Non-analytical mappings

PDE-based


That is what I was also considering. Essentially to reconstruct the boundary in reference domain, from the arc-length of the points lying on the element boundary in physical space. I suppose one can get away with the assumption of linear distances between the points, for moderate and reasonable curvature.
I thought there would be a more elegant way to do this, but I suppose one has to go through the arc length as a first step, anyway. After all, the points are ambiguous in physical domain...

@debronee101 You don't have to go with the arclength. You can also take the points at position $s\in [0,1]$ along the straight line that connects two vertices you know lie on the boundary, and then somehow project that onto the boundary. Every CAD engine supports this operation, and it's substantially cheaper than going with a fraction of the arc length between the two points you already know are on the boundary.

@WolfgangBangerth I do not agree with that. If you have the possibility to use the exact arc lengths of a polynomial curve, why not use it to distribute the points according to Legendre Gauss/Lobatto or Chebyshev Gauss/Lobatto? It is only a preprocessing step and not expensive. Later the Jacobian metrics are used millions of times in an FEM simulation and should have better properties with the exact ratios.

I'm not saying that you need to use the projection, just that you can use the projection given that the latter is typically cheaper to compute.

You perform the mapping the same way you evaluate fields at arbitrary positions in the element.
Let's start with a nodal FEM method.
Suppose you have a set of interpolation functions $\phi_i(r,s)$.
Then any scalar field $F$ is given by
$$
F(r,s) = \sum_i F_i \phi_i(r,s)
$$
where $F_i$ are the nodal values of $F$. Now substitute in each coordinate one at a time and you get
$$
x(r,s) = \sum_i x_i \phi_i(r,s)\\
y(r,s) = \sum_i y_i \phi_i(r,s)
$$
Your mesh generator will generate the nodal values $x_i$ and $y_i$, and you should know a-priori what the interpolation functions $\phi_i$ are (for example they could be tensor products of Lagrange polynomials). This directly transforms from the red nodes to blue.
It's not clear to me what your green nodes are, if your original red nodes are not the interpolation points then the mapping is ambiguous (or would have otherwise need to be specified somewhere else). In that case to find the $(r,s)$ coordinates which correspond to arbitrary global coordinates would require you to perform the inverse transform $(r,s) \rightarrow (x,y)$. You can use the Vandermonde matrix and its inverse to perform this inverse transform.
Response to edit:
First, I didn't notice before that the number of red and green nodes you have is different from the number of blue nodes. I don't know how to resolve this discrepancy.
As far as the red nodes not having the same "spacing" as the blue nodes, the mapping process can handle some amount of unequal spacing.
For example, here's a mapping onto a tensor product of Gauss-Lobatto nodes:

The black lines are contours of constant $r$ or constant $s$.
You do need to be careful with how much you deform your physical coordinate nodes, though as some mappings will generate nonsensical elements. For example, here I use the same red nodes but try to map it onto a tensor product equidistance reference element:

Here the mapping generates a self-intersecting element and will have singularities in its Jacobian. It is the responsibility of the meshing tool to not generate elements which would result in this kind of mapping at least for the mapping it intends the user to use.
If your goal with the green nodes is to find a set of nodes in reference element coordinate space where the mapping will be well defined (for example, here the GL nodes have a well defined mapping but equidistant nodes do not), then that is a much more difficult problem to solve, and I have no idea how you would do that. The mesh generator must have some sense of what mapping it was using to produce the original red nodes since otherwise it won't match the boundaries of the element correctly with the geometry.

Thank you for your answer, but let me clarify. First, the basis function $\phi$ you use already need some basis for their definition. So, if the green points are not "well-structured" in the sense they're not equidistant or LGL (etc), how can you define them?
The whole point of my question was to map them to something structured (green), such that we can define the basis functions $\phi$ and resume the formulation, as you also do.
Did that clarify things a bit?

As for what the green points are, consider a mesh generator over some curved domain. You define your geometric boundaries, assign the number of points/elements and then run an elliptic smoother. In the latter, there is no guarantee that the points are "structured" anymore (per element). Hence, the green nodes I show (as an illustration).

I didn't notice before, but your number of red points doesn't match the number of blue points. I don't know how you intend to resolve this discrepancy. There is no requirement that the points be "well structured", you can still define an interpolation basis. See for example high order triangle elements.

Thanks for the discussion. However, correct me if I'm wrong, but here you already assume the nodal distribution in the physical element is based on (Legendre-)Gauss-Lobatto. In that case, we already know their location on the reference element and all is well. The point I'm asking is: what if the physical nodes are slightly, but in a reasonable manner, random. Similar to the exaggerated red nodes in fig. (a). How would we obtain their equivalent on the reference element? Hope this makes more sense?

Also, why do you suggest that equidistant nodes don't have a well-defined mapping? If the nodes are equidistant in physical space (even if curved), they are also equidistant on the reference element. You can then form the shape (Lagrange) functions and proceed with your nodal expansion. Maybe you meant for very high order, equidistant points have bad interpolation properties?

While it is true that equidistant nodes have unfavorable properties at high order, what I mean here is the very literal the element shown in the second figure is self intersecting.

If you don't know the mapping from global coordinates to local coordinates I don't see how you can make the transformation between the two. Which is why you usually know a-priori that your reference element is GL or equidistant etc. I used your red node locations (removing them so it's 4x4 nodes instead of having a few extra on some edges).
